# Matching records from two files

Tags: bash, awk

I have one scenario wherein I have to compare two files in Linux and save the content of the first file to the output file.

**First File:**

```
user1      /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.log

user2      /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1.log
```

**Second File**

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.log: ASCII text

/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1.log: data
```

**Output Should be**

Assuming the comparison on file path string, if the file type is **data**, then 
it should print the first file content in the output file.

```
user2      /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1.log
```

I have tried to use awk with FNR==NR option, but I am not sure whether it fetch me the right result as i am new to Linux scripting.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1;
  next
}
{
  sub(/:/,"",$1)
}
($1 in a) && ($2=="data"){
  print a[$1], $1
}
' first second
```

Output will be as follows:

```
user2 /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1.log
```

Comment: @RavinderSing13 It worked.. thanks for the help and your prompt response..

Comment: @Ankug, cool, Glad that it helped you. Cheers, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge in SO :)

Comment: @RavinderSing13 can you suggest some good reference book to learn linux scripting or any website...

Comment: @Ankug, sure. Site is SO itself :) and book is O'relilley and many more basic books are there available on internet . You will find great content over SO too. Take deep breath and simply start learning from commands. My wishes are with you :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 how can we refrain the above code not to read .log files?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should also work:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*' 'FNR==NR{ if ($2=="data") a[$1]; next}
$2 in a' file2 FS='[[:blank:]]*' file1
```

```
user2      /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file1.log
```